# Python rookie: Confusing Part of an OOP Training Code

Tags: python, oop

A.

Can somebody explain what this section does in this code (http://codepad.org/SyWLTfqs)?

```
class_names = [w.capitalize() for w in
               random.sample(WORDS, snippet.count("###"))]
```

Where does the "w" come from?
Where does the function capitalize() come from?

Comment: Read about [list comprehensions](http://docs.python.org/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions) to tell where `w` comes from.

Comment: `capitilize()` is a method of all string objects.

Comment: Thanks. I have more questions:

Answer (score 1):

It's a list comprehension, iterating over a bunch of strings and calling them `w`, then calling `.capitalize()` on them. So `class_names` is a list of N capitalized randomly selected words from `WORDS`, where N is the number of occurrences of "###" in `snippet`.

Comment: Removed my answer, yours is better (and you're right about my example). I'm not new to python, but list comprehensions is not something I'm entirely familiar with.

Answer (score 1):

Firstly, note that [random.sample(input, length)](http://docs.python.org/library/random.html#random.sample) returns a list of length `snippet.count("###")` of the values of `WORDS` in random order, and capitalize is a method of the String class. 
If `WORDS` is an array of strings, that means `w` would be assigned to each string at random, applied the method `capitalize()`, and then put into a list as indicated by the brackets

Answer (score 0):

**capitize()** is a Python builtin string function that capitalizes the value in the variable **w**; a user doesn't have to create it http://docs.python.org/library/string.html. 
Basically, there's an iteration within that list variable, and the value in each iteration is assigned to the **w**.